# T-SQL USE Database - Based on Databases available in SYS tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, switch-statement

I am using Microsoft SQL Server. I have 2 environments each with its own database (`DB1` and `DB2`).

I have some code which I need to run in both environments but need it to dynamically switch which database is used based on which is available.

The SQL below is what I'm trying to achieve. However, SQL Server parses the whole statement before execution and takes issue to having `DB1` or `DB2` in the code, as it won't be available in each respective environment.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases
           WHERE name = 'DB1')
BEGIN
    USE DB1
END
 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases
           WHERE name = 'DB2')
BEGIN
    USE DB2
END
 
SELECT * FROM S_Sometable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this is to use dynamic SQL, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name='DB1')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'USE DB1';
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name='DB2')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'USE DB2';
END

SET @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + 'SELECT * FROM S_Sometable'; -- assuming that S_sometable exists in both databases

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

But be cautious with dynamic SQL. It can be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic SQL, but you don't need a `USE` statement. You can actually just call `Somedb.sys.sp_executesql`

```sql
SET @sql += CHAR(13) + 'SELECT * FROM S_Sometable'; -- assuming that S_sometable exists in both databases

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name='DB1')
BEGIN
    EXEC DB1.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name='DB2')
BEGIN
    EXEC DB2.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

If you don't know the names of the databases upfront, you can use a cursor, and parameterize the name of the procedure.

```sql
SET @sql += CHAR(13) + 'SELECT * FROM S_Sometable'; -- assuming that S_sometable exists in both databases

DECLARE @crsr CURSOR, @proc nvarchar(1000);
SET @crsr = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT name = QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.sp_executesql'
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id > 4;

OPEN @crsr;
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT @crsr INTO @proc;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK;

    EXEC @proc @sql;
END;
```